# phonegap get file inside of assets

Tags: android, ajax, file, cordova, local

I am trying phonegap at android. I have a json file inside my assets folder, such as assets/data/name.json. I wanna use it in my javascript function. I often do this before like below:

    `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ....

    xhr.open('GET', '../data/name.json');

    ....`

But I think it wasn't a good solution. Anyone has a good one?! Please tell me, thanks.

PS: Yeah, it can be loaded as an object. But are there any dynamic way to get it, cause I may have different json files to choose.

Comment: Easier method is,if you want load your json and it is in a file, and this file is located in asset, for instance you can use  a var with the json (var myjson=....)and in your code you must include <script src=./myjsonlocation.js ...> and finally you can use you json object.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your asset directory using the `file:///android_asset` path, so in your case it would be something like `xhr.open('GET', 'file:///android_asset/data/name.json');`